# Why is this method called twice?

Tags: java, methods, execution

I'm currently doing a fairly simple project for my class, but I encounter this weird problem.
Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentMain {
static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {




    System.out.println("This program allows you to organize a student's info in a clear, coherent form");
    System.out.println("Press [1] to continue");
    int x = kb.nextInt();
    if (x==1){
        Name();
        ID();

        String IDen = ID();
        String name = Name();


        System.out.println(name);

        System.out.println(IDen);
    }


}

private static String Name(){
    String SName;
    System.out.println("Enter Student name:  ");
    SName = kb.nextLine();

    return SName;
}

private static String ID(){
    String Sid;
    System.out.println("Enter Student I.D:  ");
    Sid = kb.nextLine();

    return Sid;

}
}
```

My intention for the program is listed in print statements above, but this is my biggest concern right now.
Whenever I run the program: I get this result (using it in Eclipse):

```
This program allows you to organize a student's info in a clear, coherent form
Press [1] to continue
1
Enter Student name:  
Enter Student I.D:  
John
Enter Student I.D:  
1034172
Enter Student name:  
John
John
1034172
```

As you can see, I used "John" and "1034172" as just examples, but its executing the two return methods twice. Any insight on this? All replies are welcome and greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a little time to learn the accepted [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Note: After `x = kb.nextInt()`, you probably need to add `kb.nextLine();`.  The reason is that `nextInt()` will get an integer from the keyboard but will not "eat" the newline character that follows the integer.  Then when `Name()` calls `kb.nextLine()`, it will return whatever is left on the current line, which is an empty string since the newline character on the first line wasn't yet consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling it twice as result of first method calls has not been used so those are not needed.

```
    Name();//<-------------(1)
    ID();//<-------------(1)
    //You can remove these lines

    String IDen = ID();//<-------------(2)
    String name = Name();//<-------------(2)
```

*Note:You should follow the naming conventions as method name/variable name(except constant) should start with small case.*

Here `Name();` is method call and it's upto you whether you use the returned value or not.

```
Name();//First Call
String name =Name();//Second Call
```

Comment: So by doing what you suggested, I'm automatically calling the return method and assigning it to variable? Also, is this only for return methods or can I do this for void methods also?                              Sorry, I'm very new to Java.

Comment: @AnotherNewbie Yes, `IDen = ID();` calls the method.  `ID();` [by itself] calls the method and throws away the value that `ID` returned.  You can't assign anything when you call a `void` method (`a = voidMethod();` is illegal), and a `void` method can't have a `return` that returns a value.